# jQuery checking relevant checkbox by spliting id values and matching elements accordingly

Tags: jquery, checkbox

If I have 4 divs and 4 checkboxes which each have ID's.

```
<div id="block_1"></div>
<div id="block_2"></div>
<div id="block_3"></div>
<div id="block_4"></div>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_4" />
```

I want to click the div and check the relevant checkbox. I can get the number values that I need, but struggling to match the correct checkbox when I click a div.

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var check = $('input:checkbox');

    $(this).click(function(){

        var divNum = $this.attr('id').split('block_'); 

        //Need to check the correct checkbox here

    });


    check.each(function(){

        var cid = $(this).attr('id').split('checkbox_');

    });

  });
```

Comment: The error you made in your code above is that you are attempting to trap the click event inside an each selector. It should be the other way around. Ask yourself what event will trigger the jQuery code -- *what must the user do to trigger an event*? Most often, that's a click (or a hover, or...). Your .each() selector would then be underneath the event selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify which DIV was clicked, use the jQuery `starts with` selector.

```
$('[id^=block_]').click(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('You clicked id: ' +myId);
});
```

To match the correct checkbox, use `split()` to extract the numerical portion from the rest of the ID tag, then use that number to identify the correct checkbox.

---

Full Example:  [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/F4C3L/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            div {width:50px; height:50px; background-color:red; border: 2px solid silver;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('[id^=block]').click(function() {
                    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
                    var aId = myId.split('_');
                    var idNum = aId[1];
                    alert('You clicked id: ' +idNum);

                    $('#checkbox_' + idNum).prop('checked',true);
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <div id="block_1"></div>
    <div id="block_2"></div>
    <div id="block_3"></div>
    <div id="block_4"></div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_4" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
check.filter("#checkbox_" + divNum).prop("checked", true);
```

It filters down the checkboxes to just the one with the right number in its ID, and then sets the checked property to true.

If you want to uncheck the other boxes first, you'll need

```
check.prop("checked", false)
```

before the above line to uncheck them.

Comment: Thanks, going to try .filter